# Execute Google Cloud SQL query in command line non-interactively

Tags: mysql, bash, google-cloud-sql, non-interactive

I'm writing a script to orchestrate a Google Cloud SQL instance using the `gcloud` SDK.

The SDK has a *connect* command, which takes a username but the password has to be entered at the prompt - ie it cannot be passed as an argument.

Successfully authenticating then allows a query to be executed - the flow looks like this:

```
$ gcloud sql connect instance-name --user=root
Whitelisting your IP for incoming connection for 5 minutes...done.
Connecting to database with SQL user [root].Enter password:
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 8054
Server version: 5.7.14-google-log (Google)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MySQL [(none)]> USE tablename;
```

I need to do this non-interactively. I've tried:

```
gcloud sql connect instance-name --user=root && echo "password" && echo "USE tablename;"
```

But it only executes the first command.

How can I connect, authenticate & run a query in a single command?

**Update:**

As per the comment from @danlor linking to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/338857/automatically-enter-input-in-command-line), I've tried both:

```
yes password | gcloud...
```

and

```
printf 'password\n' | gcloud...
```

but both still prompt for the password.

Comment: `&&` means that the next command will only be executed after the clean exit (success) of the previous command. That's why only the first command is being executed. Check out https://askubuntu.com/questions/338857/automatically-enter-input-in-command-line

Comment: Thanks @danlor - I've tried both `yes` and `printf` approaches in the linked answer, but neither work

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't look like the `gcloud sql connect` command give you the ability to pass in the `execute` flag to the MySQL command line utility. I would suggest using the [Cloud SQL proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy) for this instead. Your script will likely look something like the following:

```sh
./cloud_sql_proxy -dir=/cloudsql -instances=<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME> &
PID=$!
mysql -u root --password "YOUR-PASSWORD" -S /cloudsql/<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME> --execute "USE tablename;"
kill $PID
```